# where to define name of s3 bucket for different env while using fog gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I am uploading my paperclip attachment to s3 because in my model I am using fog credentials like this... The problem is I need to have different bucket names for different env, by defining the bucket in model it gets specified for every env, so where else can I define it?

```
has_attached_file :news_logo,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :fog_directory => "s3-bucket-name"
```

config/s3.yml

```
development:
  provider: AWS
  aws_access_key_id: xyz
  aws_secret_access_key: xyz
  path_style: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Rails.env** in order to customize your bucket name, like:

```
has_attached_file :news_logo,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :fog_directory => "s3-bucket-name-#{Rails.env}"
```

---

you can also do something like:

```
has_attached_file :news_logo,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :fog_directory => (case Rails.env
                       when 'production' then 'my-production-bucket'
                       when 'testing' then 'testing-bucket'
                       else 'this-is-development-bucket';
                     end)
```

Comment: but the even using this the bucket name would be same in all env, right?

Comment: The bucket name will be the same for the environment, like *s3-bucket-name-development* for development environment, *s3-bucket-name-testing* for testing environment, *s3-bucket-name-production* for production environment. You wanted to have different bucket names for different environments, right?

Comment: yeah its another good way of doing it but for this i would need to rename the bucket on aws. I am bound to use existing bucket name..

Comment: Check my edit to the answer, you can see how to set different bucket names for different environments

Comment: Thanks.. rorra great help one correction though its Rails.env instead Rails_env... but thanx..

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as follows

```
has_attached_file :news_logo,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :fog_directory => S3_BUCKET[Rails.env]
```

and define the bucket names in the constant file.

> config/initializers/constants.rb

```
S3_BUCKET = {
  'development' => 's3-bucket-name-development',
  'staging' => 's3-bucket-name-staging',
  'production' => 's3-bucket-name-production'
}.freeze
```